# Static IP for vpn client on Win 2012 R2

Tags: windows, vpn, ip, static-ip

I have Windows Server 2012 R2. I have configured VPN to the server. External clients can connect ok with AD credentials. I am able to assign static IP for specific user like in the picture below (and it works ok).

But I want to assign static IP to specific computer (not user). The setting is actually there at computer Properties (the same tab is there same as in user Properties) but the setting is ignored.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

[image: Static IP setting for user]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Network Policy Server, where you can filter the connections based on computer.